# Receiving a fixed length string on Arduino serial and storing it in a structure

Tags: c, parsing, serial-port, arduino

I am currently receiving a fixed length string means it's length cant exceed more than 50 but can be less then that.i am using following code.

```
       void loop()
{  
   char *datareceived;
   int number;
   char sword[] ="times"; 
   uint8_t x;
   digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
   number = BTSerial.available();
  // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
  if (number){

    datareceived = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*number);
   if(datareceived == 0){
   Serial.print("Error: Out of Memmory");

   }
     if(number>0){
     for(x=0;x<number;x++){
     datareceived[x]=BTSerial.read();
     if(datareceived[x] == '\n')
     //datareceived[x]='\0';
     break;

     }
     strcpy(dataReceivedfromBluetooth,datareceived);

     Serial.println(dataReceivedfromBluetooth);
     }

     if((strstr(dataReceivedfromBluetooth,sword))){
     Serial.println("Yes");
     digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
     delay(30);
     }
     else{
     digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
     }
  }
    free(datareceived);
}
```

Now with this code, it is not printing any thing at all.I think my code of dynamic memory allocation is all right.

whereas a simple code like this

```
 void loop(){
if (BTSerial.available())
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());


  if (Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

is working perfect ally fine and writing everything on serial port, so what i am trying in my main code is what ever is being received by `BTSerail.read()` is stored in a array/string and then i use that array for some of string operations like `strstsr` to find out whether that incoming string has a particular word or not.

Comment: Your code can only work properly if you get the entire message all at once.  You don't, *number* is usually 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very likely to be a problem in your code: you're not terminating the string.

A C string is just an array of characters, with a character with the value `'\0'` marking the end of the string. Unless you know that the sender includes the terminator, you're not writing one so the string just "runs off" into la-la-land.

Comment: I had used `Serial.println()` on the transmitting side, so that will by itself add a new line character at the end of string.Have a look